# Find a specific partition to make $U(f,P) < 2/100$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

" Suppose $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by
    $f(1/n) = 1/n$ when $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all other $x \in [0,1]$. Show that for some partition $P$ of $[0,1]$, we have $U(f,P) < \frac{2}{100}$" . My attempt is to subdivide the interval $[0,1]$ into subintervals with equal length $d$. Then I will make this number $d$ agree with the inequality $U(f,P) < 2/100$. But it turns out not to work well. How can I approach to solve this? 
(Let $M_k = sup \{ f(x) : x \in [x_{k-1}, x_k ] \}$ the upper sum $U(f,P) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} M_k (x_k - x_{k-1})$ and $P = \{ 0 = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = 1 \}$)

Comment: You have not defined $U(f,P)$.  What is it?

Comment: It is the Upper Sum of the function $f$. Let $M_k = \{ f(x) : x \in [x_{k-1}, x_k ] \}$ the upper sum $U(f,P) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} M_k (x_k - x_{k-1})$ and $P = \{ 0 = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = 1 \}$

Comment: How could anybody answer the question without that information?  Please edit it into your question.

Comment: I edited it to the question!!

Answer (score 1):

If subdividing into equal intervals does not work, you need to subdivide into unequal intervals.  This is a classic technique, which shows that the upper sum for any countable set like the rationals is zero.  Order the set, then put an interval of length $k$ around the first, $\frac k4$ around the second, $\frac k9$ around the third, and $\frac k{n^2}$ around the $n^{th}$.  The sum of the intervals is $\frac {k\pi^2}6$, so by choosing $k$ small enough you can get the sum as small as you want.

For your problem, equal intervals will work fine as long as you choose $d$ large enough.  The bottom subinterval will have infinitely many points in it, but will only contribute $d^2$ to the sum.  There will be only finitely many intervals above that have a $\frac 1n$ in them and each will contribute $\frac 1{nd}$ to the sum.  As long as $d$ is large enough you will be there.  Given a $d$ you need to bound this sum and you will be there.

Comment: How do you deal with the $M_k = sup ( f(x) ) $   where $x \in [x_k, x_{k-1} ] $?

Comment: In the equal interval case, by making $d$ large enough that the length of the interval is very small.  Most of the elements in the sum will be $0$ because there is not a $\frac 1n$ in the interval.  You get a harmonic sum that is about $\frac 1d \ln(n)$